# how can I click a holder in Android

Tags: android, listview, click

here are  my codes, i want to show a dialog when i click the items..
can you help me with this?
here are  my codes, i want to show a dialog when i click the items..
can you help me with this?

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView; 
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext; 
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
String targetmonth;
String targetyear;
String targetamount; 
String[] month;
String[] year;
String[] amount;


public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] month, String[] year, String[] amount) {
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.amount = amount; 
    mContext = c;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
} 
public int getCount() {
    return month.length;
} 
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
} 
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
} 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.month = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.targetmonth); 
        holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetyear); 
        holder.amount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.targetamount); 



        if (position == 0) {
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    try {

        holder.month.setText(month[position]);
        holder.year.setText(year[position]);
        holder.amount.setText(amount[position]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return convertView;
} 
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView month;
    TextView year, amount; 
}
```

}

i think in this part

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.month = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.targetmonth); 
        holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetyear); 
        holder.amount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.targetamount);
```

Main Activity.java

```
package com.demo.php.listview;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null; 
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
String targetmonth;
String targetyear;
String targetamount;
//  int responseCode;
//int listItemCount=0;
ListView listview ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setTheme(Color.WHITE); 
    setTitleColor(Color.rgb(0x74, 0, 0x37));
    setTitle("DEMO PHP");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_RIGHT_ICON); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new LoadData().execute();

} 



private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
    @Override
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","         Loading...");  
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
        try{

                 listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()]),al1.toArray(new String[al1.size()]),al2.toArray(new String[al2.size()])));
                 this.progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
            catch(Exception e){ 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }  
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        // HTTP post 
                try { 
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                    try{
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.2/android/test.php");

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
                    httppost.setEntity(se); 
                    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                    int timeoutSocket = 3000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent(); 
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    //buffered reader
                    try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 80);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    try{
                    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject json_data = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                        targetamount=json_data.getString("targetamount");
                        targetmonth=json_data.getString("targetmonth");
                        targetyear = json_data.getString("targetyear"); 
                        al.add(targetmonth); 
                        al1.add(targetyear);
                        al2.add(targetamount);  

                        //listItemCount=al2.size();
                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }  
                 catch (Exception e) {
                        //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in    http connection" + e.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }        
        return null; 
    }
} 


   }
```

Comment: What type of AdapterView is your Adapter for? ListView, GridView? I'm not sure what you mean by "how can I click a holder". You can listen for click events on child views of your Lists/Grids etc.

Comment: listview...Im just new in android..I can not declare events I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want to display a dialog when one of the items from your holder is clicked. You can try this way :

```
holder.month.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setIcon(/*Provide any drawable*/);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Alert Dialog in OnClick");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
            "Ok",
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

         alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: when I click month just force close.

Comment: Can you please show me the error from logcat? Most likely it is crashing because of 'getApplicationContext()'. Either pass context from your activity to your BaseAdapter or define your BaseAdapter in your activity that shows the list of data.

Comment: I posted the Main Activity above can you see it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

           class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

 holder = new ViewHolder();

      //Onclick for your tagetyear TextView
      holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetyear); 

        holder.year.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }
    });
   }
  }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
JSONArray jArray;
  String result = null;
  InputStream is = null;
  StringBuilder sb = null; 
  ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
  String targetmonth;
  String targetyear;
   String targetamount;
     //  int responseCode;
   //int listItemCount=0;
   ListView listview ;
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setTheme(Color.WHITE); 
setTitleColor(Color.rgb(0x74, 0, 0x37));
setTitle("DEMO PHP");
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_RIGHT_ICON); 
setContentView(R.layout.main);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
new LoadData().execute();

  } 



 private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
@Override
// can use UI thread here
protected void onPreExecute() {
this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","         Loading...");  
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
    try{

             listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()]),al1.toArray(new String[al1.size()]),al2.toArray(new String[al2.size()])));
             this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    // HTTP post 
            try { 
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                try{
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.2/android/test.php");

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
                httppost.setEntity(se); 
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                int timeoutSocket = 3000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent(); 
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //buffered reader
                try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 80);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                try{
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                    targetamount=json_data.getString("targetamount");
                    targetmonth=json_data.getString("targetmonth");
                    targetyear = json_data.getString("targetyear"); 
                    al.add(targetmonth); 
                    al1.add(targetyear);
                    al2.add(targetamount);  

                    //listItemCount=al2.size();
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }  
             catch (Exception e) {
                    //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in    http connection" + e.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }        
    return null; 
}
 } 


class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext; 
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;
 String targetmonth;
  String targetyear;
 String targetamount; 
  String[] month;
  String[] year;
  String[] amount;


  public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] month, String[] year, String[] amount) {
this.month = month;
this.year = year;
this.amount = amount; 
mContext = c;
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
 } 
  public int getCount() {
 return month.length;
 } 
public Object getItem(int position) {
return position;
 } 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  } 
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder holder = null;

holder = new ViewHolder();

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.month = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.targetmonth); 
    holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetyear); 
    holder.amount = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.targetamount); 


        //Onclick for your tagetyear TextView
  holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetyear); 

    holder.year.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
});
   }


    if (position == 0) {
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

try {

    holder.month.setText(month[position]);
    holder.year.setText(year[position]);
    holder.amount.setText(amount[position]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
return convertView;
  } 

   static class ViewHolder {
     TextView month;
    TextView year, amount; 
}

}

  }
```

Comment: Place your public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter in your activity. it will work sure.

Comment: If you didnt get still.can you post your main activity code and error log here???

Comment: I posted the Main Activity above can you see it for me?

Comment: should I put it on the main activity?

Comment: where in the main activity?..should  delete the onclick listener on the data adapter?

Comment: just put class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter in your main activity.should delete the onclick listener on the data adapter?  i can't understand this part.

Comment: I get an error in ' else 
 
 {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }

try {

    holder.month.setText(month[position]);
    holder.year.setText(year[position]);
    holder.amount.setText(amount[position]); '

in the else part

Comment: can you post your log cat?

Comment: can you include the imports?

Comment: can not see the log cat cause the program can not run because it has an error

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html please follow this link.

Comment: don't follow fully. just try to understand holder part.

Comment: do you have any tutorials that connects to mysql with the same on my situation?